# How $99^{2} \mod 32$ is equal to $3^{2} \mod 32$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I know how to get $99^{2} \mod 32$ from the $(99\mod32)(99\mod32)\mod32$ and get the answer. But the solution guide I have, has converted $$99^{2}\mod32$$ to $$3^{2}\mod32$$. Any idea how?

Comment: Hint: $99 \equiv 3 \pmod{32}$. The square thing may seem obvious now, but you should try and prove it.

Comment: Perhaps return to what it means to take $a\mod b$

Comment: See the [Congruence Power Rule.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We know that if $a \equiv b \mod n$,  then $a^2 \equiv b^2 \mod n$. If you haven't learned this yet, maybe attempt a proof.

Since $99 \equiv 3 \mod 32$ , $99^2 \equiv 3^2 = 9 \mod 32$.

Comment: If you want I can add a short proof of the fact stated above.

Comment: thanks. I just didn't know the proposition. The proof seems straightforward.

Comment: More generally, if $a\equiv a'$ and $b\equiv b'$ modulo $n$, then $a+b\equiv a'+b'$ and $ab\equiv a'b'$, both modulo $n$. I frequently found, when teaching Algebra to college juniors, that it took a good while for the power of these facts to impress itself on them.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a more concrete representation, note that

\begin{align}
99^2 & = (3 \times 32 + 3)^2 \\
     & = (3 \times 32)^2 + 2 (3)(3 \times 32) + 3^2 \\
     & = (3 \times 3 \times 32 \times 32) + (2 \times 3 \times 3 \times 32)
       + 3^2 \\
     & = (288 \times 32) + (18 \times 32) + 3^2 \\
     & = (306 \times 32) + 3^2
\end{align}

and hence $99^2 \bmod 32 = 3^2 \bmod 32 = 9 \bmod 32 = 9$.

Answer (score 0):

$$99^2 \equiv (33)^23^2\equiv 1^23^2 \equiv 3^2 \mod 32$$